# How to calculate current and voltage necessary for a solenoid to lift a given mass to a given position?

Tags: solenoid

When you have a solenoid like

[image]

without the core above and below, how do you calculate the current and voltage necessary to lift a metal rod of given mass m within the solenoid against gravity to a given position x? Let's assume the solenoid lays flat on the ground.

How do voltage and current need to change to keep the rod in a given position at x?

Comment: The image you show is a transformer, which is designed to have as little stray flux as possible, and as such, can't really lift anything. To you mean an **electo-magnet**, rather then an inductor?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnet#Force_exerted_by_magnetic_field

Comment: @starblue Your link is not valid as it does not deal with different separation of each turn.

Comment: Furthermore, the overall lifting capability of an electromagnet is going to be **MASSIVELY** dependent on the core topology.

Comment: @Fake Name is correct in his first comment, and his point is important.  A transformer, which is what you show, is intended to have as little external magnetic flux as possible, whereas the whole point of a electromagnet is to create external magnetic flux to that it can perform work.  You need to listen to what he said.  It is your comment, not his, that is not helpful in finding a solution.

Answer (score 3):

There is no general equation.

The lifting power of an electromagnet is dependent on a large array of things, and is far more complex then can simply be calculated based on the voltage and current.

The most important here is the magnetic core or armature. Also relevant is the coil topology, the magnetic permissivity of the core material, the permissivity of the material the magnet is attracting, and the shape of the object the magnet is attracting.

You also seem to be using a few terms incorrectly. A "solenoid" is a type of electromagnet, which is a type of esoteric inductor.

If you have a commercial solenoid, really your only hope is to contact the manufacturer of your device. If this is something you built yourself, you're pretty much going to have to actually physically measure the performance.

Note that a solenoid is a type of electromagnet where the moving armature is generally cylindrically shaped, and moves within a tubular coil. A solenoid is an electromagnet, whereas not all electromagnets are solenoids.

---

If you want to play around with computer simulations, [FEMM](http://www.femm.info/wiki/HomePage) is a cool tool for magnetics modeling. However, it is a 2D simulator only. Modeling magnetic fields with any resolution in 3D is only available in massively expensive simulation tools, and even simple simulation take many hours of computation, and are only as good as your model is accurate.

[image]

Comment: Agree with all the above. If it's commercial it'll have a datasheet. Simple. If it's custom, get cutting metal, winding wire, measuring force. You can apply basic theory in a spreadsheet but when I tried, and THEN compared with practice, I was off by 3x. (No allowance for fringing, I think). So apply theory, make, measure, refine the model, try again.